# NVM Command Not Found

Tags: nodejs

I am trying to install [node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and followed the installation instructions provided at its Github page.

Installation got over but now I am getting an error as `command not found: nvm` when I try using `nvm install 0.8`

Can someone please help me find out why I am gettting an error that `nvm` is not found when I have already installed it.

Comment: What steps did you already take? Was the installation successful?

Comment: Please post the commands (and their output) you ran before `nvm install 0.8`.

Comment: Apparently you did *not* install it.

Comment: Close and open your Terminal. Type the following command to verify nvm command works. nvm

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you need `nvm` to be automatically sourced upon login, so either add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file.

```
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Also `nvm` doesn't set any version of node automatically so if you just installed `nvm` and installed a node version and try to use `node` the next time you login, you get an error that `command not found: node` unless you use the `nvm use versionnumber` command in every terminal session, so Instead I suggest you to set a default alias so that a default version of node is active for every terminal session using the following command

```
nvm alias default versionnumber
```

*PS: In the above commands version number denotes the version number of `nodejs` that you have already installed using `nvm`*

Comment: this is not working: `no such file or directory`

Answer (score 11):

Simply Try

1. `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
2. Then You Can Easily: `nvm install 0.10`

Comment: that may work temporarily, but will you need to re-source the file for every terminal session?