# NVM Command Not Found Issue

Tags: git, nodejs

Attempted to add to this question: [NVM Command Not Found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269631/nvm-command-not-found), however wasn't able to.

After installing nvm im having the same issue, here is the log from terminal:

```
Michael-iMac:~ michaels_imac$ curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1202  100  1202    0     0   5759      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6829
=> NVM is already installed in /Users/michaels_imac/.nvm, trying to update
=>  
Already up-to-date.

Michaels-iMac:~ michaels_imac$ nvm install 0.8

-bash: nvm: command not found
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem seems to be that gnome terminal does not load `~/.profile` on startup, and there is where NVM is added to the path. You have two choices:

- Go to "Edit" -> "Profile Preferences" in terminal and activate "Run command as a login shell". Then close and open again the terminal.

[image]

- Add this at the end of `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  [[ -s /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh
  ```

Comment: Idiotically I've just realised since im using OS X this is not the ideal location for this question, I posted here due to this being the only place I found a question on nvm. I dont suppose you know the OSX Terminal equivalent solution to this, or what i should be searching for? Apologies.

Comment: If you are using bash as shell the second way still works (to know which shell you are running use `echo $SHELL`). If you are using zsh the correct file is `~/.zshrc`. Also check [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/).

Comment: entering echo $SHELL returns /bin/bash, im not sure where to go from here. Have tried entering what you suggested above and just get a new line the same as the one previous. Do i need to navigate to bashrc before entering [[ -s /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh? Sorry about my lack of command line experience.

Comment: You need to open `.bashrc` (it is a hidden file located on your home folder: if it doesn't exist you can create a blank one) with a text editor and add `[[ -s /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh` at the end.

Comment: @dntz Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

i think you have miss this step

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

You can run this command on the bash OR you can but under the file /.bashrc or ~/.profile to automatically load

REF::https://github.com/creationix/nvm